# How to remove nil entries from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a Mutable Dictionary that I removed an element from with removeObjectForKey. That's fine, but when I enumerate thru the Dictionary, there is a 'hole' for the element I deleted. So when I print the Dictionary, it displays that element as (null).

Is there way to 'pack' the dictionary after removing an element? I need contiguous numbers for the keys. Example:

BEFORE DELETE:

```
key:1 value:red
key:2 value:green
key:3 value:blue
key:4 value:yellow

myDictionary removeObjectForKey:2
```

CURRENT:

```
key:1 value:red
key:3 value:blue
key:4 value:yellow
```

DESIRED:

```
key:1 value:red
key:**2** value:blue
key:**3** value:yellow
```

Code to remove nil entry from `NSMutableDictionary`. This is what I came up with, but it is not working:

```
int count = dictFaves.count;
int x = 1;  // Dictionaries are 1-relative
while ( x <= count ) {

   // get the current row
   NSString *curRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x];
   NSString *temp = [dictFaves objectForKey:curRow];

   // is this row empty? if so, we have found our hole to plug
   if ( temp == nil ) {
       // copy the Fave from the 'next' row to the 'current' row. Effectively   
       //   shifting it 1 lower in the Dictionary
       NSString *nextRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x + 1];
       temp = [dictFaves objectForKey:nextRow];
       [dictFaves setObject:temp forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];

       // one final thing to cleanup: remove the old 'next' row. 
       // It has been moved up 1 slot (along with all others)
       [dictFaves removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x+1]];
   }
   x = x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because the `NSDictionary` (and its mutable subclass) acts like a hash/map/associative array. If you want to keep the indices running consecutively, you have to either reset them after removing an object, or just store everything in a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm too far into the design to change to NSMutableArray. Poor planning. I don't need the indices to run consecutively - I would be happy if I can remove the hole in the Dictionary created by removing an entry. I added code above to do this, but it is not working...

Comment: @Bassman: What hole are you talking about? I thought "hole" was a way of saying "the numbers aren't consecutive."

Comment: If you don't want to use a mutable array, then you gotta iterate through the dictionary and manually set the keys to suit your requirements.

Comment: @Chuck: yes, the numbers are no longer consecutive once I delete an entry.

Comment: @Alexander: I took your suggestion. Works like a champ. The only problem now is that UITableView reloads before I can remove the null entry. It aborts when it hits that entry. I just posted another question to that effect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alexander: I bit the bullet and took your original suggestion to use NSMutableArray instead of NSMutableDictionary. Not only did it work, but other code became much simpler. I was clearly using the wrong class for the job. I probably replaced 50 lines with 2 lines. Thank you!